# How throwing exception in catch block works in java using throw and how the control goes back to throw again after finally block is executed?

Tags: java

```
public class MultipleCatch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      int s = 42 / 0;
      int c[] = {1};
      c[10] = 25;
    } catch (ArithmeticException ae) {
      System.out.println(ae);
      throw ae;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ai) {
      System.out.println(ai);
    } finally {
      System.out.println("finally");
    }
    System.out.println("Exception handled");
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
finally
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Exception.code.MultipleCatch.main(MultipleCatch.java:8)
```

Comment: @Blobonat The OP made an MCVE to illustrate a problem. This is not production code. So your comment is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

> How throwing exception in catch block works in java using throw?

An exception thrown in the `catch` block causes control to leave the entire `try-catch-finally` statement and then (after the code in the `finally` block is executed) bubbles up the call stack as usual until it is handled somewhere.

Note that it won't be caught by other `catch` blocks (e.g. one for `Exception` or `RuntimeException`) within the same `try-catch-finally` statement it originated in.

> And how the control goes back to throw again after finally block is executed?

Control never returns to the place where the exception was thrown. After the code in the `finally` block is executed, it continues *after* the entire `try-catch-finally` statement (or after another `try-catch-finally` statement somewhere higher up the call stack).

So, in your code, the line `int c[] = {1};` is perfectly unreachable.